# split value of bootstrap multiselect value into multiple variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

please help
 i have my multi select value

```
var branch=$('#branch').value;
//branch = 101,102,103;
```

i want it to get separately as

```
id='101' or id='102'...
```

as i want pass it into MySQL query where part via an ajax call,my exact query will be as follows

```
select * from company where id='101' or id='102'....
```

Thanks in advance for your response

Comment: `branch.split(",")` - gives you an array. Loop over array to form query.

Comment: Did you realize that what you want to do won't return `true` in any case?  Probably, you want to use `OR` instead!

Comment: A recommendation, don't do that in client-side to avoid SQL injection.  Do that, in server-side instead, receiving those ids as string seperated by comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `branch` variable contains the comma separated string, you can use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to convert that to an array.

Then you need to loop through the array changing each value to get preceded by `id=`, and then finally you need to join the resultant array using `OR`.

Following is the working code of making it work:

```js
let branch = "101,102,103";
let result = branch.split(',')
  .map(item => `id=${item}`)
  .join(' OR ');

console.log(result);
```